# networkx is_isomorphic taking weights into account

Tags: python, graph, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def is_isomorphic(graph1, graph2):
    G1 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(graph1)
    G2 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(graph2)
    isomorphic = nx.is_isomorphic(G1,G2)
    print("isomorphic? \t", str(isomorphic))
    return isomorphic


graph1 = np.array([[1, 0.5, 1.5],
                   [0, 1,   0],
                   [0, 0,   2]])

graph2 = np.array([[1,  0, 1.5],
                   [0,  1, 1.5],
                   [0,  0, 2]])

print(is_isomorphic(graph1,graph2))
```

Suppose I have two graphs: `graph1` with node 1 being bonded with a node 1 and 2 and `graph2` where node 2 is being bonded with two node 1s. So if we look at these graphs as molecules, these two graphs are not isomorphic. Now when I call `is_isomorphic()`, this results in a `True` value, meaning that the two graphs are isomorphic.

How do I make sure that the weights are being taken into account?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - your code won't run right now.  Can you fix it so that it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iso.categorical_edge_match`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.categorical_edge_match.html) to define a comparison function, so that in checking if both networks are isomorphic, the edge `weight` attributes are taken into account:

```
G1 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(graph1)
G2 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(graph2)
```

Note that the weights, are basically just edge attributes:

```
G1.edges(data=True)
# EdgeDataView([(0, 0, {'weight': 1.0}), (0, 1, {'weight': 0.5})...
G2.edges(data=True)
# EdgeDataView([(0, 0, {'weight': 1.0}), (0, 2, {'weight': 1.5})...
```

So we want to define a comparison function in which these attributes are compared when `iso.categorical_edge_match` receives two edges from `G1` and `G2`:

```
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso
em = iso.categorical_edge_match('weight', 'weight')
```

Now when using `nx.is_isomorphic` set `edge_match` to the comparison function `em` defined above with `iso.categorical_edge_match`, so that it is called with each edge being compared to check if their weights are equal:

```
nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2, edge_match=em)
# False
```

Since `edge_match` expects a callable, and we only want to compare on an attribute, in this case we could also define our own *simple* comparison function so that  the edge attributes are also considered:

```
nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2, edge_match=lambda x,y: x['weight']==y['weight'])
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

In [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic) for `nx.is_isomorphic`, there is an option of a argument `edge_match`.  It returns `True` or `False` based on whether you want the edges to be considered a match:

> The function will be called like
>   edge_match(G1[u1][v1], G2[u2][v2]).

Here's an example:

```
nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2, edge_match=lambda x, y: x==y)
```

Comment: Thanks! I already saw the edge_match argument, but was  confused that it needed a "callable" input. This helped too!